# The Sibling Function

Tags: jquery

I would like to know what are the requirements for the sibling() function. For instance which selector will come in the parameters () if the html is as below and I am targeting the now div class and could you explain in a bit of detail which parent element or what is suppose to be in the parameters. Thanks all help is appreciated

```
   $(function(){
          $(".target").click(function(){
              $(this).siblings(".a_cont").slideDown(100);
          });
   })

<div class='yes'>
  <div class='what'> 
    <button class='target'> </button>
    <div class='now'> </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='yes'>
<div class='what'> 
    <button class='target'> </button>
    <div class='now'> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery API documentation is really usually quite helpful.  [This](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) is the page on .siblings().

The documentation states:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .siblings() method allows us to search through the siblings of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.
>
> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type that we can pass to the $() function. If the selector is supplied, the elements will be filtered by testing whether they match it.

So you start with a jQuery object, such as `$(this)` in your example.  `.siblings()` will find all of the sibling elements in the DOM tree, and the result is a new jQuery object.  The selector allows you to filter out elements.  So to do what you want from the button that has your handler requires the code:

```
$(this).siblings(".now");
```

That takes the class now as the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this :
css:

```
.now {
    width:100%; 
    height:100px; 
    display:none;
 }
```

html :
        
        
            target
            target.sibling

```
<div class="yes">
    <div class="what">
        <button class="target">target</button>
        <div class="now">target.sibling</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js :

```
 $(function () {
            $(".target").click(function () {
                $(this).siblings().slideDown(100);
            });          
        })
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer by saying why this works?